# Windows Vista not booting properly

Tags: windows, windows-vista, boot

My Windows Vista Home Basic machine is not booting properly - it gets stuck after this screen:

[image]

When I force a restart, it sometimes gives a 'Startup Repair' option. However having used it once, it only asks me to restore the system to a stable point, and it is not a permanent solution.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with booting the Windows Vista installation CD and choosing "Repair your computer",  this sometimes help.

If this doesn't work, you should try Safe mode, this will show the drivers the windows is loading. when it stops, you will know the last driver that was loaded successfully.
Then you should update your question, this will help others help you.